# Passing JavaScript objects with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a form on my website which collects data and posts using jquery to be handled using c#. I use request.form to capture the form data.

My friend said to create a JavaScript object to pass the data through instead of loads of variables. My problem is when you post an object with value pairs how do you get c# to obtain the values from the object because I can't seem to use request.form now.

Comment: Could you post some code? I would think that it always send it as "post" values, which you should be able to get it with request.form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.js has Stringify() which convert your js object to Json String so in C# you can deserialize this string back to an object

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)? That makes JSON (de)serialization pretty easy

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a built in JavaScript (i.e. JSON) serializer.  It is in System.Web.Extensions.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

 // To serialize
 Dictionary<string, object> test = new Dictionary<string, object>(){ { "a", 1 } };
 string json = serializer.Serialize(test);

 // To deserialize (convert back to a .NET object)
 Dictionary<string, object> result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 hidden field and put a JSON value/pair string in that field and then parse it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the issue. 
When posting the data I had to use Request instead of Request.Form. Now the values are being passed back. Sorry if I did not include any code and I think the question I asked was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: You should accept your answer so people know this question is resolved.